# Python Json Error , Expectiing comma delimitter

Tags: python, python-jsonschema

I tried many ways but not sure why this error coming. This is small script I am trying on SPYDER.
Please help.

```
import json

myjson = '''
[
   "details":[
      {
         "MyTable":"NEWTABLE",
         "ReferTo":"Test"
      },
   ]
]
'''
data = json.loads(myjson)  

###  ABOVE LINE IS THROWING ERROR, --->  Expecting ',' delimiter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure is incorrect. it should be a list of dict or a direct dict

**Ex:**

```
myjson = '''{
   "details":[
      {
         "MyTable":"NEWTABLE",
         "ReferTo":"Test"
      },
   ]
}'''
```

Or

```
myjson = '''[
    {
    "details":[
        {
            "MyTable":"NEWTABLE",
            "ReferTo":"Test"
        },
    ]}
]'''

import ast
print(ast.literal_eval(myjson))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python lists could not recognize `key: value` items so as the result while json tries to decode the string it's expecting `,` after `"details"` but it's getting `:` instead and throws `JsonDecodeError`.

so either you should use bracers `{}` instead of brackets `[]`:

```
myjson = '''
{
    "details":[
        {
            "MyTable":"NEWTABLE",
            "ReferTo":"Test"
        },
    ]
}
'''
```

or if you want to use lists you should wrap your inside items into dictionary:

```
myjson = '''
[
  {
    "details":[
        {
            "MyTable":"NEWTABLE",
            "ReferTo":"Test"
        },
    ]
  }
]
'''
```

then you can easily use `json.loads(myjson)`